# Track first observation based on several criteria in R

Tags: r

I'd like a way to go through 2 million rows in R, and find the *first* instance of when *specified* events occur, and track the times they occur. Notes: (1)`start event` times should occur before `end event x` and (2) `end event x`/`end event z` in row 1 should occur before `start event` in row 2, etc.

The closest other example I've found is: [R - Keep first observation per group identified by multiple variables (Stata equivalent "bys var1 var2 : keep if _n == 1")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553235/r-keep-first-observation-per-group-identified-by-multiple-variables-stata-equ)    ;

my question is *different* because I need to 1) look at multiple criteria and only include rows if they meet criteria (`threshold`, `status`, etc.), and 2) need to format it differently (i.e. pull the `Timestamp` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr), [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr), and [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table). `case_when` is handy to assign the condition. After that, drop rows with NA in `Flag`, and then assign run length ID in `Flag2`, filter the first row in `Flag2`, assign `Flag2`, and finally spread the data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(Flag = case_when(
    Enable == 0 & Deviation > Threshold & Status == 0        ~ "Start Event Time",
    Enable == 1 & Deviation > Threshold & Status == 0        ~ "End Event x Time",
    Enable == 1 & Deviation > Threshold & Status == 1        ~ "End Event z Time",
    TRUE                                                     ~ NA_character_
  )) %>%
  drop_na(Flag) %>%
  mutate(Flag2 = rleid(Flag)) %>%
  group_by(Flag2) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(x=cumsum(Flag == "Start Event Time")) %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  filter(!(duplicated(Flag) & (Flag =='End Event x Time' | Flag =='End Event z Time'))) %>% 
  spread(Flag, Timestamp, x) %>%
  select(ID, `Start Event Time`, `End Event x Time`, `End Event z Time`)
dat2
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   ID    `Start Event Time` `End Event x Time` `End Event z Time`
# * <chr> <chr>              <chr>              <chr>             
# 1 a     6/10/2015 10:20    6/10/2015 10:25    6/10/2015 10:40   
# 2 a     6/10/2015 10:55    6/10/2015 11:00    6/10/2015 11:10   
# 3 b     7/11/2015 11:25    7/12/2015 11:30    7/13/2015 11:35
```

Comment: this worked perfectly on the sample data set I used yesterday, but when using on the larger sample data set that I uploaded, it throws an `Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (7, 9), (4, 6)`

Comment: @Meg I am happy to help, but please understand that it takes time and effort to research your question and develop an answer. When you replaced your example dataset to a new one, I feel a little bit been offended as all these time and efforts are not worthy. It is you who provided the example dataset yesterday, don't you have the responsibility to make sure your example dataset truly represent your real-world data? If the code cannot work because example dataset and real word dataset differ a lot, why not post a new question? Why change your original question?

Comment: goodness I didn't mean to offend you at all! - I really appreciate all of your help- I go through each step of your code to better understand your approach, and research each function. I'm only a couple mo into R (which is not an excuse), but I am sloowly getting the hang of reproducible data and understanding all of the potential issues with data (my earlier questions were downvoted often). But you're right, next time I post a question, Ill double check that data is representative enough, sorry if I upset you at all - I really do appreciate the time you put into helping newbies like me.

Comment: I ended up coupling your answer with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48528734/remove-duplicates-based-on-order to complete this! thanks again! R is beautiful! :P

Comment: @halfmeggle Good work. I think I overreacted a little bit. Sorry for that. If you like, feel free to edit my post with your updated code. I think it would be good contribution to the community as others will benefit from your code. Once you finished your edits, I will approve it.

Comment: thank you! And no worries, you had every right to call me out ;) I am still trying to understand your thought process here :P Thanks again for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most elegant solution but it appears to get the job done.

```
library(tidyverse)
d <- read_csv(
"ID,  Timestamp,        Enable,      Status,     Deviation,   Threshold
a,   6/10/2015 10:10,     0,           0,           0.5,     0.65
a,   6/10/2015 10:15,     0,           0,           0.6,     0.65
a,   6/10/2015 10:20,     0,           0,           0.75,    0.65
a,   6/10/2015 10:25,     1,           0,           0.8,     0.65
a,   6/10/2015 10:30,     1,           0,           0.9,     0.65
a,   6/10/2015 10:35,     1,           0,           0.8,     0.65
a,   6/10/2015 10:40,     1,           1,           0.7,     0.65
a,   6/10/2015 10:45,     1,           1,           0.5,     0.65
a,   6/10/2015 10:50,     0,           0,           0.6,     0.65
a,   6/10/2015 10:55,     0,           0,           0.7,     0.65
a,   6/10/2015 11:00,     1,           0,           0.8,     0.65
a,   6/10/2015 11:05,     1,           0,           0.9,     0.65
a,   6/10/2015 11:10,     1,           1,           1,       0.65
a,   6/10/2015 11:15,     1,           1,           0.8,     0.65
a,   6/10/2015 11:20,     1,           1,           0.7,     0.65
b,   7/10/2015 11:20,     0,           0,           0.4,     0.5
b,   7/11/2015 11:25,     0,           0,           0.6,     0.5
b,   7/12/2015 11:30,     1,           0,           0.7,     0.5
b,   7/13/2015 11:35,     1,           1,           0.8,     0.5")

d %>% 
  mutate(
    start = ifelse(Enable == 0 & Deviation > Threshold & Status == 0,
               1, 
               0),
    end_x = ifelse(Enable == 1 & Deviation > Threshold, 
               1, 
               0),
    end_z = ifelse(Enable == 1 & Deviation > Threshold & Status == 1, 
               1, 
               0)) %>%
  gather(var, val, start:end_z) %>% # gather them into a single variable
  filter(val == 1) %>% # remove dummy coding
  select(ID, Timestamp, var) %>% # remove unnecessary variables
  group_by(ID, var) %>% 
  mutate(count = 1:n()) %>% # create count variable so rows are uniquely identified
  spread(var, Timestamp) %>% # spread it back out
  select(ID, start, end_x, end_z) %>% 
  na.omit()

  ID    start           end_x           end_z          
  <chr> <chr>           <chr>           <chr>          
1 a     6/10/2015 10:20 6/10/2015 10:25 6/10/2015 10:40
2 a     6/10/2015 10:55 6/10/2015 10:30 6/10/2015 11:10
3 b     7/11/2015 11:25 7/12/2015 11:30 7/13/2015 11:35
```

Comment: so close! I appreciate the quick response! Only issue I can see is that the starting events would need to happen before the end events (see row #2) - almost there though! :)

Comment: Wouldn't that (start events before end events) be a logical constraint? Can something end before it began?

Comment: Okay, but given the criteria and data you've provided, I believe the above is correct. If you look at row 5 of your data it meets the criteria for `end_x`, even if the time is before the row that matches the criteria for `start`, unless I'm misinterpreting?

Comment: Daniel Anderson - you're right, I didn't specify (I'll just editted it to be more clear) - but yes, it would be a restraint that the start events need to happen before the end events (which I think probably makes it more tricky)

Comment: Daniel Anderson - I also made another note (I found this bug while applying your solution to my own code) - end times at row 1 should occur before start times at row 2; thanks again for the help on this - I tried using arrange() by Timestamp right after the `filter(val == 1)` line

Answer (score 1):

For each 'ID', use `cumsum` to create a grouping variable 'g', based on condition for 'start'. For each 'ID' and 'g', select relevant rows.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)
d[ , g := cumsum(Enable == 0 & Deviation > Threshold & Status == 0), by = ID]
d[g > 0, .(start = Timestamp[1],
           end_x = Timestamp[Enable == 1 & Deviation > Threshold][1],
           end_z = Timestamp[Enable == 1 & Deviation > Threshold & Status == 1][1]),
  by = .(ID, g)]
#       ID g              start              end_x              end_z
# 1:     a 1    6/10/2015 10:20    6/10/2015 10:25    6/10/2015 10:40
# 2:     a 2    6/10/2015 10:55    6/10/2015 11:00    6/10/2015 11:10
# 3:     b 1    7/11/2015 11:25    7/12/2015 11:30    7/13/2015 11:35
```

Comment: Henrik - thank you for the answer. I added additional data to the csv to better map for the oddities in my data. It looks like your solution tracks the first event, but doesn't match it  (see below:    ID g           start           end_x           end_z
1:  a 1 6/10/2015 10:11              NA              NA
2:  a 2 6/10/2015 10:12              NA              NA
3:  a 3 6/10/2015 10:13              NA              NA
4:  a 4 6/10/2015 10:14 6/10/2015 10:15 6/10/2015 10:45
5:  a 5 6/10/2015 10:55 6/10/2015 11:00 6/10/2015 11:10
6:  b 1 7/10/2015 11:22 7/11/2015 11:24 7/11/2015 11:27)

Comment: Please take your time to construct example data of sufficient complexity _before_ posting your question. It's rather frustrating spending time on a valid answer, solving the original problem, which is then turned invalid by a moving target question. Cheers.

Comment: Apologies for that - I really appreciate your help with this and I definitely got a chance to explore `data table` more with your answer. It's not an excuse, but I have been at R for a couple months, and am still getting the hang of reproducible data, and am particularly struggling with trying to think of possible issues with my actual dataset. I really appreciate you and others, and your contribution to SO - and I apologize for making you frustrated for my obvious newbiness