# R: Removing (or grouping) redundant observations/duplicates

Tags: r

I have a spotify dataset with a lot of observations.

A problem I run into with the dataset, is that a lot of (almost) duplicated observations occur.
This happens when a song has multiple genres instead of just one, since this will create another observation identical with the other except the `genre` variable will be different. In the dataset, one song can have up to 4 different genres, which creates a lot of redundant data.

*What is the best way to deal with this?*

**What I am trying to do:**

I have changed the categorical `genre` variable to a dummy variable, this creates additional variables in the dataset, one for each genre.

Next I want to sum the dummy variables for each unique song that has multiple genres, so I can remove (or group) duplicate observations afterwards, but I'm not sure how to go about this part.

*Example with mock data:*

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fastDummies)

song_and_artist <- c("song_by_band", "song_by_band", "song_by_band", "othersong_by_otherband", "othersong_by_otherband")
genre <- c("pop", "rock", "hiphop", "rock", "pop")
popularity <- c(85, 85, 85, 58, 58)

df <- data.frame(song_and_artist,genre,popularity)
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
> df
         song_and_artist  genre popularity
1           song_by_band    pop         85
2           song_by_band   rock         85
3           song_by_band hiphop         85
4 othersong_by_otherband   rock         58
5 othersong_by_otherband    pop         58
```

I transform the `genre` variable to dummies.

```
dummy_df <- df %>% 
  dummy_cols(select_columns = 'genre') %>% 
  select(-genre)
```

This leaves me with a dataframe looking like this:

```
> dummy_df
         song_and_artist popularity genre_hiphop genre_pop genre_rock
1           song_by_band         85            0         1          0
2           song_by_band         85            0         0          1
3           song_by_band         85            1         0          0
4 othersong_by_otherband         58            0         0          1
5 othersong_by_otherband         58            0         1          0
```

What is the best way to get from this, to this:

```
> dummy_df
         song_and_artist popularity genre_hiphop genre_pop genre_rock
1           song_by_band         85            1         1          1
2 othersong_by_otherband         58            0         1          1
```

I hope this was able to explain what my problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = genre,
              names_prefix = "genre_",
              values_from = genre) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("genre"), ~+!is.na(.)))
```

instead of `dummy_cols`. This returns

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  song_and_artist        popularity genre_pop genre_rock genre_hiphop
  <chr>                       <dbl>     <int>      <int>        <int>
1 song_by_band                   85         1          1            1
2 othersong_by_otherband         58         1          1            0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dummy_df %>%
  group_by(song_and_artist, popularity) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), sum), .groups = "drop") # thanks Martin Gal!
```

Or I slightly prefer:

```
dummy_df %>%
  group_by(song_and_artist) %>%
  summarize(across(-popularity, sum))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), song_and_artist + popularity ~ genre, length)
          song_and_artist popularity hiphop pop rock
1: othersong_by_otherband         58      0   1    1
2:           song_by_band         85      1   1    1
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is really the same as keeping one row per song and drop the `genre` column. The following post already answers in great detail how to do just that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21553539/16240751

Comment: I actually don't think that's the same. Since OP doesn't want one single row to be kept but the rows to be summed up into one row.

Comment: Right Martin Gal, I missed that.